# How to validate third party JWT tokens

Tags: amazon-web-services, jwt, amazon-cognito

Scenario: A .net core Web Api that can be consumed by different application that all have their own authentication/authorization and sent JWTs with every request.

Without having to write custom implementations for each identity provider is it possible to for example use a cognito user pool that has all these identity providers connected so that when a JWT needs to be validated it will validate to the correct identity provider?
For example lets say the application got a JWT from OpenId provider, it passes this JWT to the Web API, this Web API then validate the JWT thru cognito -> OpenId provder?

Somehow im unable to find answers to this so im also open to any best practices for this.

Comment: Small but important remark: access tokens are (should be) generated for a specific consumer (= audience). Meaning that you should not accept tokens that have an audience ("aud") other then your api. Also you have to (explicitly) decide which tokens you accept. Be aware that literally everyone can generate and sign a valid JWT token. So just receiving a correctly formatted and signed token with the correct aud and all means nothing if you don't know and trust the issuer.
Now that we have this out of the way, if you want any easy solution, use authO (not free)

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I understand we should not accept any valid access_token but i hoped there would be a solution where cognito will validate the token to the respective federated identity. So if a access_token created by google comes by it will validate it using the federated identity of google(that is setup in the cognito user pool configuration). If a valid access token of amazon comes by but this is not configured as federated identity it will not validate.